# How to printf to next line when function is executed for the 2nd time in C?

Tags: c

Solving a problem. But my output is not matching with the expected output.

Input:

```
2
16
10
```

Expected Output:

```
16 11 6 1 -4 1 6 11 16
10 5 0 5 10
```

Actual Result:

```
16 11 6 1 -4 1 6 11 16 10 5 0 5 10
```

I have almost tried all the escape sequences, i.e. `"\n"` `"\t"`, etc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void printPattern(int n, int m, bool flag) {
    printf("%d ", m);

    if (flag == false && n == m)
        return;

    if (flag) {
        if (m - 5 > 0)
            printPattern(n, m - 5, true);
        else
            printPattern(n, m - 5, false);
    } else 
        printPattern(n, m + 5, false);        

    //return 0;
}

int main() {
    //int n = 16;

    int t, n;
    scanf("%d", &t);

    while (t-- > 0) {
        scanf("%d", &n);
        printPattern(n, n, true);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
2
16
10
```

Expected Output:

```
16 11 6 1 -4 1 6 11 16
10 5 0 5 10
```

Actual Result:

```
16 11 6 1 -4 1 6 11 16 10 5 0 5 10
```

Comment: The header files are: #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

Comment: Add a `printf("\n");` at the end of `printPattern`? What do you mean by " almost tried all the escape sequences, i.e. "\n" "\t", etc. "?

Comment: Edit to reformat your code.

Comment: I don't see any `'\n'` in your code. Not even one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to print a linefeed after you invoke printPattern in the loop.

```
while(t-->0){
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printPattern(n,n,true);
    printf("\n");
}
```

I wouldn't put the linefeed print in the recursive `printPattern` function itself. You want to print one line for each number you're reading from input and this solution best reflects your intent.

You could also do `putchar('\n')` instead of `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

Add `printf("\n")` after the second time you call `printPattern()`:

```
void printPattern(int n,int m, bool flag)
{
    printf("%d ", m);
    if(flag == false && n==m)
        return;
    if(flag)
        if(m-5>0)
            printPattern(n,m-5, true);
        else
        {
            printPattern(n,m-5,false);
            printf("\r\n"); /* Sometimes the carriage return is required in Windows
                               operating systems to simulate line break... */
        }
    else 
      printPattern(n,m+5,false);        
}
```

Comment: It's clearer to put the linefeed in the while loop. Here you have to study the function to see if there's any way that the initial call can exit without encountering the linefeed print.

Comment: @WillisBlackburn You are right... It is just another way to tackle the problem...

Comment: This is an "interesting" program. The intent seems to be to count down by 5 until we hit the first number <= 0, then count up by 5 to the original number... all using recursion. The variable `flag` is true if we're counting down, false if counting up. You have put your `printf` at the point where the function invokes itself to start counting up, and that call won't exit until the program has counted back up to the starting point. So it should work in all cases. I think it would also work right before the `return` statement.

Comment: `printf("\r\n");` -> **NO!** not needed. Just use `printf("\n");`

Comment: @chqrlie writes this because the convention in C is that \n is the line terminator and that the output device takes care of issuing whatever characters are necessary to start a new line. The standard library also accounts for platform differences in line endings when working with files in text mode.